# Detect the Touch pad status(ON/OFF) in UWP

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I want to detect the touch pad status whether it is on or off in the UWP application.on search i am to find only the click event which does not meet my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TouchCapabilities class's TouchPresent property to see if a touch device is present

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Input.TouchCapabilities

Comment: It will Get me the Touch status of the Screen. I want the TouchPad status